# iOS - how to create a "material design" compliant UIView with shadow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, material-design

I'm trying to see if there's a way to create a UIView with [a shadow behavior compliant with material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/objects-in-3d-space.html#objects-in-3d-space-elevation-android-). My understanding is that the shadow gets more intense as the object is further removed from the background surface.

I can manually add a shadow like this, however this shadow does not calculate how intense the shadow should be (based on Z order).

```
    button.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:button.layer.bounds cornerRadius:11].CGPath;
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
    button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

**How do I create a UIView which will behave like Google's material design?** I [found this example, called Material Kit](https://github.com/nghialv/MaterialKit), however it simply hides shadow on touch

> One way in which Google does this is by emphasizing the use of a
>   **‘z-axis’ to create a sense of depth in which elements can occupy
>   different levels.** In order to show that an element is occupying a
>   higher level on the z-axis, shadows are used around its border, being
>   cast on to the level below. What this creates is the illusion of an
>   interactive layer/element that exists above a different, lower
>   interactive layer/element.

[image]

Comment: I think that the question is not related that much to shadow, which is just a visual effect, but more on how do you determine a "fake z". On what level are objects. So, is it with a long press? For example, the more your maintain a touch on your UIView, the more z should grow (until a limit)? Then, it's about calculating the "long press time".

Comment: For timing of long press, BFPaperButton has a good solution - the "tap circle" grows up to a certain maximum on long press and stays there, but just ripples in and out on tap.

Comment: semi related: ive had performance issues using the shadow property of `UIViews` before if they are quite a few elements on screen. it could be wiser to have a UIImage with a baked in shadow that is the background of a container that you put your element into giving it the appearance of having a shadow, without it having to be rendered by the layer

Answer (score 7):

You could subclass `UIButton`, and first set the shadow properties to your liking:

```
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
button.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
```

Then change the `shadowOpacity` property when the highlighted state changes:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = (highlighted ? 0.85 : 0);
}
```

Comment: But this will work if maskToBounds=NO, in case of Corner radius we will need to turn MaskToBounds to YES, in that case this shadow will also masked out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply both a shadow and a rounded corner, you need to use 2 nested views. This is because the two effects require competing `masksToBounds` properties.

Nest 2 UIViews. Apply the shadow to the outer view, setting `masksToBounds = false`. Then apply the rounded corner to the inner view, which requires `masksToBounds = true`.

Note that, according to Apple docs, `masksToBounds` is equivalent to `clipsToBounds`.